# Chatbot Watson - Limitar quantidade de vezes que diálogo cai em um nó

Tags: chatbot

Estou desenvolvendo um chatbot no Watson Conversations e me deparei com uma necessidade útil para o diálogo.
Preciso que se o diálogo cair no anything_else 3 vezes o bot pule para um diálogo solicitando informações de contato do usuário, para entrarmos em contato com ele.
Já está tudo pronto no geral. Só estou com essa dificuldade e não encontrei nenhuma solução próximo dessa que resolva meu problema.

Comment: Já resolvi!
Sugestão dada por um amigo no Stack em Inglês.
Ele sugeriu inicializar uma variável no início do diálogo zerada, e ir incrementando ela a cada vez que o diálogo caísse num nó específico que eu precisasse. E depois usasse essa variável como critério para o nó que queria acionar. Funcionou exatamente como eu precisava.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução simples seria adicionar um "Multiple Response" no "anythingelse" , sendo que a terceira mensagem consista em uma regra para o seu código, assim, você ao receber essa regra comandaria onde e  o que fazer com a próxima resposta do usuário.